# C# creating an implicit conversion for generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generics class that I used to write data to IsolatedStorage.

I can use an `static implicit operator T()` to convert from my Generic class to the Generic Parameter `T`

e.g.

```
MyClass<double> foo = new MyClass(187.0);

double t = foo;
```

My question is, how can I do the reverse?

```
MyClass<double> foo = new MyClass(187.0);
double t = 0.2d;
foo = t;
```

The implicit operator has to be static, so I'm not sure how I can pass in the instance of my class?

Comment: How are you defining the second implicit operator?  It should look like a mirror image of the first (with the types reversed).  Does that not work?

Comment: That works, but I was hoping to use a class method, instead of constructing a new object.

Comment: ok, but yeah, does not work that way.  Type conversion should always produce a new instance of a type.  (and really, those types should be immutable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT:

If you want to be able to change the value of `T` in your class, I would recommend exposing it as a property like:

```
T Value { get; set; }
```

That will allow you to change the value, instead of the behavior of the implicit operator returning an entirely new instance of the class.

---

You can and can't using implicit operators.  Doing something like

```
 public static implicit operator int(MyType m) 
 public static implicit operator MyType(int m)
```

will implicitly convert from `MyType` to `int` and from `int` to `MyType` respectively.  However, you're right, since they are static, the `int` to `MyType` specifically will have to create a new instance of `MyType` and return that.

So this code:

```
MyClass<double> foo = new MyClass(187.0);
double t = 0.2d;
foo = t;
```

wouldn't replace the value in `foo` with `t`, the implicit operator would return an *entirely new* `MyClass` from `t` and assign that to `Foo`.

Comment: To your edit, that's how I'm doing it today. I just thought it would be more slick to not use `.Value` everywhere.

Comment: I would use `.Value` everywhere.  It keeps your code cleaner and more readable.  Implicit operators are handy, but overuse can easily make your code difficult to read.  You're doing it the right way.

Answer (score 22):

This class shows conversion between T and MyClass, both ways.

```
class MyClass<T>
{
  public MyClass(T val)
  {
     Value = val;
  }

  public T Value { get; set; }

  public static implicit operator MyClass<T>(T someValue)
  {
     return new MyClass<T>(someValue);
  }

  public static implicit operator T(MyClass<T> myClassInstance)
  {
     return myClassInstance.Value;
  }
}
```

Comment: See additional question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618845/implicit-operator-with-generic-not-working-for-interface

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to convert the other way by simply specifying another implicit operator:

```
public static implicit operator MyClass<T>(T input)
{
   return new MyClass<T>(input);
}
```