# Implicit C# Conversion For Generic Wrapper Class

Tags: c#, generics, casting, implicit-conversion

I'm writing a generic wrapper class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for a bunch of properties within another one of my classes.  I've been doing some research on the [`implicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) conversion operator, but I'm a bit confused on how to use it within a generic class.  Essentially I would like to get the internally wrapped value without needing to explicitly call the internal property.  The behavior I am looking for is essentially how the [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) class/struct works where if the internal value is not `null`, then it will return the internally wrapped value directly.  Example below:

```
//current behavior
MyWrapperClass<int> wrapped = new MyWrapperClass();
int startCount = wrapped.Data;

//behavior I am looking to implement
int startCount = wrapped
```

In the second example above wrapped will return it's internally wrapped value instead of type T instead of having to call the inner property.  This is how `Nullable<T>` behaves.

When looking into implicit conversions it appeared that I needed to know the type before hand per this MSDN article: [Using Conversion Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx)

Do I need to convert on a `dynamic` type since the type is not known?  Example:

```
public static implicit operator dynamic(MyWrapperClass w)
```

Or can I perform implicit conversion on type T as seen below?  This would prevent me from making the method static, which I noticed is used in all the sample code I've seen involving both implicit and explicit conversion operators.  This option seems "wrong" to me, but I could not find much information on the subject here.

```
public implicit operator T(MyWrapperClass w)
```

EDIT:  This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946412/c-sharp-creating-an-implicit-conversion-for-generic-class) might cause this to be labeled as a dupe, but the accepted answer is not what I am looking for since they say to use the property which I am already doing.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question - but just an observation... can you use AOP to make your class implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Something like Fody https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged or Postsharp http://www.postsharp.net ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I've never used Fody or PostSharp before but I'll definitely look into it.  Essentially this is being done so if properties are modified a flag will be set to save them back out to the configuration file that originally generated them.  Would you have an example on how to use either of those solutions to do this?

Comment: Fody is easy - use NuGet to get Fody (the PropertyChanged.Fody will do) installed into your project and then decorate your class with [ImplementPropertyChanged]... that's it - your properties now implement INotifyPropertyChanged when built! I know PostSharp can do it (google LocationInterceptionAspect for doing it yourself), but I have be free licence and this is a 'paid for' feature so I've never done it by the magic attribute. Both of these weave the implementation of INotifyPropertyChged into the output code after it has been compiled by MSBuild (I think - it's kinda like magic!) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

After some testing it appears that the second option works without issue and still allows itself to be static.  I used @AndersForsgren's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946412/c-sharp-creating-an-implicit-conversion-for-generic-class) (not accepted answer) to figure this out.  Apparently I misunderstood how the implicit operator overload works.  The code snippet that corrects this is as follows:

```
public static implicit operator T(WrapperClass<T> input)
{
     return input.Data;
}
```