# C# Down casting Parent Object to Subclasses

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, downcast

I receive a list of Parent Objects(Devices) and would like to convert each Device Object into a subclass Object. The layout would looks something along the lines of:

```
public class Device
{
    public string FimrwareVersion { get; set; }

    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public string DeviceType { get; set; }

    public string AppServerUrl { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class SmartLightBulb : Device
{
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }

    public int State { get; set; }

    // Turn On/Off
    public async Task ToggleState()
    {
        // Toggle State
    }

    ...
}


public class SmartPlug : Device
{
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }

    public int State { get; set; }

    // stay on for X
    public async Task SetTimer()
    {
        // Set Timer
    }

    ...
}

public class Lb100 : SmartLightBulb 
{

    public async Task ChangeBrightness(int brightness)
    {
        // Change Brightness
    }
}

public class Lb200 : SmartLightBulb 
{

    public async Task ChangeBrightness(int brightness)
    {
        // Change Brightness
    }

    public async Task ChangeColor()
    {
        // Change Color
    }
}
```

The issue is that I receive a list of Devices and I cannot downcast from Device to Lb100. I would Like for Lb100 to maintain all of the properties that were received from the Device Class, and also take the functionality of the Lb100. I have heard of reflection, but I have also heard that this is a very slow process and should be avoided when possible.

What would be perfect is if I could just go:

```
var device = new Device(){ Firmware = "V1.4"...};
var lb100 = (Lb100) device;
```

I also understand that the reason down casting is not possible is because when the parent object is created, it allocates just enough memory for the object of that type. Then when you try and cast it to a larger subclass, you are trying to fit that larger subclass into that allocated space.

From the research that I have gathered, this way of thinking when programming is incorrect, but no one really mentions the correct way of thinking through this issue. Other users mention that they create a constructor that manually sets each property equal to each other; but this seems like a major hassle for maintaining code, especially when more devices and models are being added. Thanks for any advice that you can provide!!

Comment: Derived class constructors that take an instance of the base class are the way to do it.

Comment: You could implement IConvertable in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Or serialize / deserialize your object `var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);` `var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChildType>(serialized);` with Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the idea of polymorphism in object oriented programming. I would read up on this to start with

Comment: Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39618845/1026459

Comment: You may want to read Eric Lippert's excellent post on [representation and identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast to subclass, you only need to verify if it can be casted.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var smartLightBulb = new SmartLightBulb()
        {
            DeviceType = "deviceType",
            Model = "model"
        };
        Output(smartLightBulb);
    }

    public static void Output(Device device)
    {
        var smartLightBulb = (device as SmartLightBulb);
        if(smartLightBulb != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(smartLightBulb.Model);
        }
    }
}

public class Device
{
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
}

public class SmartLightBulb : Device
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Antonio, thanks for the quick response! The only issue is that in your example, you start with a SmartLightBulb, I sadly start with a device. Your solution does get me closer to the end goal seeing that it no longer throws the "Cannot cast from Device to SmartLightBulb" exception. The new lightbulb that is returned is null. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You can down cast (from super to parent) as that's just removing fields.
E.g. an lb100 is a type of device.

But you can't up cast (from parent to super) as that needs additional data.
E.g. a device is not a type of lb100.

Comment: You're reversing the usual terminology. [Downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) is conventionally casting from a less derived type to a more derived one, the opposite of what you're saying. Also, in C#, such a "cast" a) doesn't require a cast operation and b) doesn't actually *change the representation at all*. No fields are "removed".