# implicitly convert a generic type object

Tags: c#

I have a class like this:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator T(Response<T> res)
    {
        return res.Value;
    }
}
```

I consume the implicit operator in three ways:

```
public void Demo()
{           
    IList<int> good = test() as IList<int>; // This line is no problem 
    string good2 = test2(); // This line is no problem 
    IList<int> bad = test(); //Why this line doesn't work?
}

public Response<IList<int>> test()
{
    return new Response<IList<int>>();
}
public Response<string> test2()
{
    return new Response<string>();
}
```

Why `IList<int> bad = test()` can't work but shows "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Response>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: The first `good` won't fault at runtime because it will result in `null` if the conversion fails, as has happened in this case: `good` is `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found your answer buried deep inside the c# language specification, in the part that talks about [Conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#conversion-operators):

> If T is an interface type, user-defined implicit conversions from S to T are ignored.

Which means that if you change `IList` to `List`, implicit conversion should work just fine:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<int> good = test() as IList<int>; // This line is no problem 
    string good2 = test2(); // This line is no problem 
    List<int> good3 = test3(); // This line works as well
    //IList<int> bad = test(); // This fails...
}

static Response<IList<int>> test()
{
    return new Response<IList<int>>();
}

static Response<List<int>> test3()
{
    return new Response<List<int>>();
}
static Response<string> test2()
{
    return new Response<string>();
}
```

Comment: I found a similar explanation by Eric Lippert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39619053/3181933).

Answer (score -1):

You are casting the result of test() to IList, thats why the line

```
 IList<int> good = test() as IList<int>;
```

compiles, but good will always be null as you cannot cast Response> to IList

Comment: Yes, and OP's question is about why they can't cast `Response<IList<int>>` to `IList<int>`.